# Yii2 delete confirmation modal

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I'm trying to make a delete confirmation modal with yii2. 
I have a grid view with an action button which deletes item of gridview.

When a user clicks on this button, a popup modal shows up and I cannot get the id of the item which must be deleted.

Here the code of my gridview (only the action button):

```
'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                            return Html::a('', $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open']);
                        },
            'edit'   => function ($url, $model) {
                            if (Yii::$app->user->getIdGroupe() != 1)
                            {
                                return Html::a('');
                            }
                            return Html::a('', $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-pencil']);
                        },
                        'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                            return Html::a('', $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash', 'data-toggle' => 'modal', 'data-target' => '#modal', 'data-id' => $model->idRessource, 'id' => 'popupModal']);
                        },
                ],
'urlCreator'  => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                            if ($action == 'view') {
                                $url = Url::to(['/ressource/view', 'id' => $model->idRessource]);
                            } else if ($action == 'edit') {
                                $url = Url::to(['/ressource/edit', 'id' => $model->idRessource]);
                            } else {
                                $url = '#';
                            }
                            return $url;
                    },
```

Then the modal :

```
<?php $url = Url::to(['ressource/delete']); ?>

<?php Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2 class="modal-title"></h2>',
    'id'     => 'modal-delete',
    'footer' => Html::a('Supprimer', $url, ['class' => 'btn btn-danger']),
]); ?>

<?= 'Etes vous sur de vouloir supprimer la ressource ...'; ?>

<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

And finally javascript :

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$(function() {
   $('#popupModal').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#modal-delete').modal('show').find('.modal-body')
        .load($('.modal-dialog'));
        var modal = $(this);
        var triggered = $(e.relatedTarget);
        var id = triggered.data('id');
        $('.modal-title').text('Supprimer la ressource ' + id);
   });
});"); ?>
```

And the problem is I can't get the id of the item and I need it when I build the $url because the action 'actionDelete' need the id of the item.

Hope it is clear and you'll be able to help me ! 
Thanks

Comment: actionDelete() requires id via post method.

Comment: I use my own `actionDelete()` but thanks for the advice ! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution by myself and thanks to @XiaosongGuo so here is the full answer

My delete button :

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
    return Html::a('', $url, [
        'class'       => 'btn btn-danger btn-xs glyphicon glyphicon-trash popup-modal',
        'data-toggle' => 'modal',
        'data-target' => '#modal',
        'data-id'     => $model->idRessource,
        'data-name'   => $model->nomRessource,
        'id'          => 'popupModal',
    ]);
},
```

My url creator :

```
'urlCreator'     => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
    $url = Url::to(['/ressource/delete', 'id' => $model->idRessource]);
    return $url;
},
```

My modal :

```
<?php Modal::begin([
    'header' => '<h2 class="modal-title"></h2>',
    'id'     => 'modal-delete',
    'footer' => Html::a('Supprimer', '', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'id' => 'delete-confirm']),
]); ?>

<?= 'Etes vous sur de vouloir supprimer cette ressource ?'; ?>

<?php Modal::end(); ?>
```

and finally the JavaScript :

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("
    $(function() {
        $('.popup-modal').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var modal = $('#modal-delete').modal('show');
            modal.find('.modal-body').load($('.modal-dialog'));
            var that = $(this);
            var id = that.data('id');
            var name = that.data('name');
            modal.find('.modal-title').text('Supprimer la ressource \"' + name + '\"');

            $('#delete-confirm').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                window.location = 'delete?id='+id;
            });
        });
    });"
);
```

If you have better solutions than my answer please do not hesitate to tell me !

Thanks for the help everyone :)

Comment: By default the action 'delete' only accepts 'post' method. `<a data-pjax="0" data-method="post" data-confirm="您确定要删除此项吗？" aria-label="删除" title="删除" href="URL HERE"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a>`. Use these code that is creating by GridView.

Answer (score 2):

PHP buttons:

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
    return Html::a('', $url, [
        'class' => '... popup-modal', 
        'data-toggle' => 'modal', 
        'data-target' => '#modal', 
        'data-id' => $model->idRessource, 
        'id' => 'popupModal-'. $model->idRessource
    ]);
},
```

Js:

```
<?php
$this->registerJs("$(function() {
$('.popup-modal').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var modal = $('#modal-delete').modal('show');
    modal.find('.modal-body').load($('.modal-dialog'));
    var that = $(this);
    var id = that.data('id');
    modal.find('.modal-title').text('Supprimer la ressource ' + id);
});
});"); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man it works but now I have the id (in JS) how can I get it in PHP ?

Comment: I found the solution, I will post the full answer by myself, thanks a lot for your help I will quote you :)

Answer (score 0):

is it possible to put the id in the model url similar to:

```
<?php $url = Url::to(['ressource/delete', 'id' => $model->id]); ?>
```

Comment: `'id' => $model->id]);`

Comment: I can't use `$model->id` outside anonymous functions (where I defined each button or the urlCreator) so that my problem :/

Answer (score 0):

It appears Yii already has the javascript for prompting a confirmation dialogue box and PHP Helper for the button/link.

Ref: [Simple analysis of post requests implemented with yii helpers Html class and yii.js of yii2](https://programmer.group/5c23c692e0988.html)

Pasting the code below for quick reference:

```
<?= Html::a(
      'delete',
      [
          'delete',
          'id' => $id,
      ],
      [
          'data' => [
              'confirm' => 'Are you sure you want to delete it?',
              'method' => 'post',
          ],
      ]  ) 
?>
```